# Storing WHERE clauses in a global table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running this query 50+ times, and I want to abstract the AND query statements below and store them in one/global table, so in the future I only have to edit one table (vs. 50) if I want to edit any of the AND statements.  What's the most efficient way to store the AND statements in a separate table and then cal them in the below query?

```
SELECT  
    Field,
    Field2,
    Field3
    into table1
FROM    table2
WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%ADVANCE%AUTO%Pa%')

AND is_duplicate!=1
AND amount >0 
AND currency_id = 152 
AND transaction_base_type = 'debit' 
AND TRANSACTION_STATUS <> 'D'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a view/[materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-creatematerializedview.html):

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT  
    Field,
    Field2,
    Field3,
    DESCRIPTION
FROM    table2
WHERE  is_duplicate!=1
    AND amount >0 
    AND currency_id = 152 
    AND transaction_base_type = 'debit' 
    AND TRANSACTION_STATUS <> 'D'
```

and then:

```
SELECT Field, Field2, Field3
FROM my_view
WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%ADVANCE%AUTO%Pa%')
```

---

### EDIT

> I simply need to store WHERE clauses in one place so I can update them once and call them in 50 queries vs. including them in every query and updating them 50 times. Is it really that complicated?

As I wrote in comment you cannot simply parametrize table name(plus it may indicate that [schema is flawed](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table)). SQL is powerful language so you could use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ecpg-dynamic.html) and functions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(tab_name text)
RETURNS TABLE (
   id INT,     -- here goes common column list shared across all 50 tables
   col1 INT,
   col2 INT
 )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY 
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * from %I where col2 > 0',tab_name);
                                     -- here goes shared conditions
END 
$BODY$;

SELECT * FROM my_func('tab1');
SELECT * FROM my_func('tab2') WHERE col2 = 2;
                              -- condition that is not shared
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7be0385ddbc8d66427a0367452a81392)**

Comment: Is there a way you can edit the view where it only contains the AND statements?  Is there a way to avoid querying table2 until the final query (i.e., the one with WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%ADVANCE%AUTO%Pa%'))

Comment: @ZJAY Yes, you could ALTER VIEW if needed. Then you query only my_view

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz Szozda.  Could I write the view with simply the AND statements, no queries?  I don't want to write any queries in the view, just have the criteria for the WHERE statements I am accessing in other 50 queries.  Is this possible?

Comment: @ Lukasz Szozda this is not the correct solution because I can only run my_view against table2.  But the whole point was to create a global query I can run across 50 different tables, but just edit the WHERE clauses in one place when necessary.

Comment: `"create a global query I can run across 50 different tables"` then you need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ecpg-dynamic.html). You cannot simply parametrize table name. And if you have the same where conditions it looks like your design is flawed ([table per date/client/...](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table))

Comment: I simply need to store WHERE clauses in one place so I can update them once and call them in 50 queries vs. including them in every query and updating them 50 times.  Is it really that complicated?

Comment: @ZJAY Please check the revised answer.